# Не вызывается функция. No matching function for call to C++

Tags: c++, функции

Не получается вызвать функцию, выдает следующее:
"No matching function for call to 'seidel'" и "No matching function for call to 'main_element'".
Не могу понять что нужно исправить, буду благодарна за решение и объяснение.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void seidel ( int n, double a[n][n], double e)
{
    int i;
    double x[3], x_k[3];
    double o = 1;
    int iteraction = 1;
    while (o > e)
    {
        x_k[0]=(a[0][3]-x[1]*a[0][1]-x[2]*a[0][2])/a[0][0];
        x_k[1]=(a[1][3]-x_k[0]*a[1][0]-x[2]*a[1][2])/a[1][1];
        x_k[2]=(a[2][3]-x_k[0]*a[2][0]-x_k[1]*a[2][1])/a[2][2];

        o = abs(x_k[0] - x[0]);

        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (abs(x_k[i] - x[i]) > o) {
                o = abs(x_k[i] - x[i]);
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            x[i] = x_k[i];
            cout <<setprecision(15)<<x_k[i] << "   ";
        }
        cout << "Ітерація №" << iteraction << endl;
        iteraction++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "x" << i << "= " << x[i] << endl;
    }

}
void main_element( int n, double a[n][n])
{int i, j, m, k;
    double aa, bb;
    double* x;
    x = (double *)malloc(n* sizeof(double));
    if (a[0][0] == 0)   
    {
        cout<<"Система не має рішень"<<endl;
    }
    for (k = 0; k<n; k++) 
    {
        aa = fabs(a[k][k]);
        i = k;
        for(m = k+1; m<n; m++)
            if(fabs(a[m][k])>aa)
            {
                i = m;
                aa = fabs(a[m][k]);
            }


        if (i != k)  
        {
            for (j=k; j < n+1; j++)
            {
                bb = a[k][j];
                a[k][j] = a[i][j];
                a[i][j] = bb;
            }
        }
        aa = a[k][k];
        a[k][k] = 1;
        for (j=k+1;j<n+1;j++)
            a[k][j] = a[k][j]/aa;
        for (i = k+1; i < n; i++)
        {
            bb = a[i][k];
            a[i][k] = 0;
            if (bb!=0)
                for (j=k+1; j< n+1; j++)
                    a[i][j]=a[i][j]-bb*a[k][j];
        }
    }

    for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--)   
    {
        x[i] = 0;
        aa = a[i][n];
        for (j = n; j>i; j--)
            aa = aa-a[i][j]*x[j];
        x[i] = aa;
    }

    cout<<endl;  
    for (i = 0; i< n; i++)
    {
        cout<<"x["<<i+1<<"]="<<x[i];
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    const int n=3;
    int a[n][n+1]={{  10,   -1, 2,   16},   
                      {2, -7,  4, 14},
                      {1, 1,  -5,   -14}};
double e;
    cout<<"Введіть точність: ";
    cin>>e;

    seidel(n,a[n][n], e);
    main_element(n, a[n][n]);


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Всегда помните, что у вас в сигнатуре `T[R][C]` будет преобразован в `T(*)[C]`.

Comment: Вы можете передавать массив по ссылке: `void main_element(int n, double (&a)[n][n])`

Comment: Больше того, вам для этого не нужно передавать `n`. Вы можете взять его из `NTTP` (шаблоны), т.к. размер массива является частью его типа.

Comment: А вообще, у вас ведь банально матрица не квадратная.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iomanip>

constexpr int rows = 3;
constexpr int cols = rows+1;

void seidel (double (&a)[rows][cols], double e)
{
    // ...
}

void main_element(double (&a)[rows][cols])
{
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    system("chcp 65001");

    int array[rows][cols] = {
        { 10, -1,  2,   16 },   
        { 2,  -7,  4,   14 },
        { 1,   1, -5,  -14 }
    };

    double e;
    std::cout << "Введіть точність: ";
    std::cin >> e;

    seidel(array,e);
    main_element(array);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```